# How to use React.forwardRef?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass ref to a child component with `forwardRef`, but `current` for the given ref is always `null`. Why?

Consider this simple example:

```
// Details.jsx
import { useRef, forwardRef } from 'react';

const Details = () => {
    const usernameRef = useRef(null);

    const InputClipboardButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
        <ClipboardButton targetInputRef={ref} />
    ));

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" ref={usernameRef} />
            <InputClipboardButton ref={usernameRef} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

```
// ClipboardButton.jsx
const ClipboardButton = ({ targetInputRef }) => {
    const copyToClipboard = () => {
        console.log(targetInputRef);
    }

    <button onClick={copyToClipboard}>
        Copy
    </button>
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `forwardRef` you must be mindful of the order of the parameters passed (`props` and `ref`):

You can define the component like so:

```
const FancyButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton">
    {props.children}
  </button>
));
```

**Note** how `forwardRef` takes two parameters:

1. The props
2. The `ref` being forwarded

You may also destructure the `props` value, as well as call the `ref` property a different name:

```
const FancyButton = React.forwardRef(({
  btnType,
  children
}, forwardedRef) => (
  <button ref={forwardedRef} type={btnType} className="FancyButton">
    {children}
  </button>
));
```

```
// You can now get a ref directly to the DOM button:
const ref = React.createRef();
<FancyButton ref={ref} btnType="button">Click me!</FancyButton>;
```

Example adapted from [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

Comment: Well, it seems `forwardRef` does  not work the way I expected to. I just wanted to pass ref of the input field in `Details` to `ClipboardButton`. Example given in the docs is essentially backwards, acquiring ref of the child component, which is not my intent.

Comment: In your example, you are passing `targetInputRef` as a normal prop, not passing it in using the `ref` keyword. You may use `forwardRef` without assigning the ref to the child component or pass it as a simple prop (without using `forwardRef`). If you wish to grab an input's value for the `onClick` you could always curry the `copyToClipboard` function or define it in the parent

Answer (score 0):

Clipboard Button is a component, so you must use forwardRef in this component as well

```
    const ClipboardButton = forwardRef((props,ref) => {
        const copyToClipboard = () => {
           console.log(ref);
        }

        <button onClick={copyToClipboard}>
            Copy
        </button>
   });
```